# I can't run a Data Explorer query - the captcha won't show up

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha

On RPG.SE, we're engaging in some comment cleanup practices [on our meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/a-chart-of-comments-per-user). For this purpose, one of the moderators put together a data explorer query to dig up comments that might need cleanup:

https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/182189/worst-comments-per-user?UserId=760

I'd like to run this for myself, but the captcha isn't showing up so I can't prove I'm human!

> [image]

"Maybe I just have to click the button?" I wondered to myself, but when I try it I get this:

> [image]

I'm running Firefox Aurora 30.0a2. My addons are Adblock Plus, Grease Monkey with the Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch, and Ghosterly. However: this is the same with ABP and SOUP disabled, and the data explorer added to Ghosterly's whitelist.

Comment: @michaelb958 Argh! Thanks for pointing that out. Removing the solitary S works.